# Unable to compile downloaded binaries when executing elm-test

Tags: elm

I am unable to run my unit tests via the command line:

```
elm-test
```

> PS C:\my_path\client> elm-test Downloading binaries from
>   https://dl.bintray.com/elmlang/elm-test/0.18.6/win32-x64.tar.gz
>   Compilation failed for
>   C:\my_path\client\elm-stuff\generated-code\elm-community\elm-test\src\Mainc5862d6
>   a0878fab784555034eda0ebc7.elm

Note:
I'm not sure if this is a bug on the package or if it's within my control.

Comment: I had the same with Linux, and I think the solution (see #testing channel n elm slack) is to install elm-test locally rather than globally

Comment: I attempted your suggestion. However, I'm still observing the same error.

Comment: I had a similar issue last week. Are you using `create-elm-app`?

Comment: No. I'm not. But if I were?

Comment: @ScottNimrod I started to have that error when I upgraded from `create-elm-app` @ 0.2.4 to 1.0.0, I'm not sure if it is because they use a different version of `elm-test`.  So maybe the problem you are having can be for having a different version of `elm-test` ...

Comment: @ScottNimrod have you tried `elm-test@0.18.7`?

Comment: @Halfzebra - That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unluckily for you, you've got `elm-test@0.18.6`, which had a few bugs in it.

The latest version should fix the issue.